# how to re position the key of an object in a JSON using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two objects which I need to compare. However there is a problem in the position of the keys in an object.

```
var obj1 = [{
    Name : abc;
    age : 23;
}, {
    Name : def;
    age : 222;
}]

var obj2 = [{
    age : 23;
    Name: abc;
}, {
    age : 222;
    Name : def;
}]
```

I have tried using the below, but it failed.

```
(JSON.stringify(obj1) == JSON.stringify(obj2))
```

Is there a way to swap the position of the keys in an object which iterates throughout the object? I am expecting something like this

```
var obj1 = [{
    Name : abc;
    age : 23;
}, {
    Name : def;
    age : 222;
}]

var obj2 = [{
    Name : abc;
    age : 23;
}, {
    Name : def;
    age : 222;
}]
```

Comment: The order of the keys in an object is not guaranteed, so what you're trying to do is redundant. As you've seen objects cannot be directly compared. Instead, compare their properties, eg. `obj1.Name == obj2.Name && obj1.age == obj2.age`

Comment: Keys are not ordered in a Javascript object, do not count on it :)

Comment: what problem you face with this dis order?

Comment: his problem is actually to compare 2 arrays of object (sequentially), he tries stringifying them using JSON before comparing the result strings but the mismatched order of declared keys makes them uncomparable.

Comment: I am not able to control the order of the keys in the object. is there a way i can re arrange?

Comment: @James each item in array is object, and comparing each element is a must-do in sequential comparing 2 arrays.

Comment: You can use [lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual) `isEqual` to compare objects. Also, you can create a similar function by searching for object deepEqual on google.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is one more catch there are multiple objects in the array so it might not work

Comment: In which case you'd need to loop through them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RoryMcCrossan said -

> The order of the keys in an object is not guaranteed

You should use this code instead

```js
var obj1 = [{
  Name: 'abc',
  age: 23
}, {
  Name: 'def',
  age: 222
}];

var obj2 = [{
  age: 23,
  Name: 'abc'
}, {
  age: 222,
  Name: 'def'
}];

function isEqual(objA, objB) {
  if (objA.length !== objB.length)
    return false;
  let isequal = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < objA.length; i++) {
    if (objA[i].Name !== objB[i].Name || objA[i].age !== objB[i].age)
      isequal = false;
  }
  return isequal;
}

if(isEqual(obj1, obj2)){
  console.log("Equal");
}else{
  console.log("Not equal");
}
```

Comment: How dose this iterate through obj2?

Comment: @HemanthPaluri I am using a `for` loop to iterate over `obj1`. I am also using this index for `obj2`

Comment: One more thing on success of complete comparison only it should come to body of either if or else because i am calling services based on the success or fail. In the above code for each iteration it will go to body right? so how do i overcome this?

Comment: like if(Condition){body}else{body}

Comment: @HemanthPaluri Answer updated. + You should follow some basic javascript tutorials

Answer (score 1):

The keys of an object (unordered) is different from the index of an array (ordered).  To compare two arrays of objects and see if they have the same object (with the same key/value pairs) in each of the array elements, you can try this:

```
function compareArrayOfObjects(array1, array2) {
  return array1.reduce(function(bool, obj, index) {
    return bool && array2[index] && isEqual(obj, array2[index]);
  }, array1.length === array2.length);
}
```

If you simply need to compare values as simple as numbers and strings, you can implement isEqual() as follows:

```
function isEqual(a, b) {
  var aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
  var bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

  return aKeys.reduce(function(bool, aKey) {
    return bool && (a[aKey] === b[aKey]);
  }, aKeys.length === bKeys.length);
}
```

If you need deep object comparisons then you probably want a LoDash implementation of _.isEqual().

To put it all together, you will have

```js
    var obj1 = [{
      Name: 'abc',
      age: 23
    }, {
      Name: 'def',
      age: 222
    }];

    var obj2 = [{
      age: 23,
      Name: 'abc'
    }, {
      age: 222,
      Name: 'def'
    }];
    var obj3 = [{}, {}];
    
    function compareArrayOfObjects(array1, array2) {
      return array1.reduce(function(bool, obj, index) {
        return bool && array2[index] && isEqual(obj, array2[index]);
      }, array1.length === array2.length);
    }

    function isEqual(a, b) {
      var aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
      var bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

      return aKeys.reduce(function(bool, aKey) {
        return bool && (a[aKey] === b[aKey]);
      }, aKeys.length === bKeys.length);
    }
    console.log('obj1 and obj2 is the same (expected true): ' + compareArrayOfObjects(obj1, obj2));
    console.log('obj1 and obj3 is the same (expected false): ' + compareArrayOfObjects(obj1, obj3));
```

Comment: are you sure that the `return false;` inside forEach's callback should affect as `return false;` for the `isEqual`? I think you need some variable before the `forEach`, set that to `false` inside the callback and check that variable after the `forEach`. However using `every` is better in this case.

Comment: exactly i was about to comment same :)

Comment: @Hopeless my bad!  Thanks for pointing it out... and I have edited the code to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the keys in an object is not guaranteed, so any attempt to rearrange them would be redundant.

However given your description, this seems to be an XY problem, as your goal is to compare the objects. The issue you have is that objects cannot be directly compared. Instead, compare their properties, eg.

```
if (obj1[i].Name == obj2[i].Name && obj1[i].age == obj2[i].age) {
  // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well there is better way though examples above will work but they will fail for unknown keys.

```
function compareArrayObjects(ob1, ob2) {
  let ob1Keys = Object.keys(ob1);
  let ob2Keys = Object.keys(ob2);
  return (ob1Keys.length == ob2Keys.length?(ob1Keys.every(key)=>(obj1[key]==ob2[key]))
   :false); 

}
```

or 1 line solution will be

```
_.intersection(obj1,obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as all the other answer already tell you, you'll have to compare the keys, not the objects themselves. Just adding another implementation

```js
function isObject(value) {
  return typeof value === "object" && value !== null;
}

function isSimilar(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;
  return isObject(a) && isObject(b) &&
    Object.keys(a).every(key => a[key] === undefined || key in b && isSimilar(a[key], b[key])) &&
    Object.keys(b).every(key => b[key] === undefined || key in a);
}


var obj1 = [{
  Name: 'abc',
  age: 23,
  thisKeyIsIgnoredSinceItIsUndefined: undefined
}, {
  Name: 'def',
  age: 222
}];

var obj2 = [{
  age: 23,
  Name: 'abc'
}, {
  age: 222,
  Name: 'def'
}];

console.log(isSimilar(obj1, obj2))
```